# Unable to read input from jar

Tags: java

When I run `java -jar MidiTest.jar`, input a MIDI file, it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.media.sound.StandardMidiFileReader.getSequence(StandardMidi
leReader.java:209)
        at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSequence(MidiSystem.java:802)
        at MidiTest.playMidi(MidiTest.java:56)
        at MidiTest.(MidiTest.java:44)
        at MidiTest.main(MidiTest.java:25)
```

If I use `java MidiTest` instead it could play without issue. What wrong with the code? I have already add `Main-Class: MidiTest` with newline on Manifest file

My code:

```
        private void playMidi() {
    if(isPlaying.equals("0")) {
        try {
            song = MidiSystem.getSequence(
                getClass().getResource(filename));
            sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.setSequence(song);
            sequencer.open();
            sequencer.addMetaEventListener(this);
            sequencer.start();
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad midi file: "
                + filename);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            System.out.println("No sequencer available");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not read: "
                + filename);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        displayMidiInfo(filename);
        } else {
        updateTempoFactor(speed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with how you're accessing the file, but we need to see your code to really help you with this one.

Comment: Ok, I've add my code. My input is "MidiFileNewsong.mid" which will then strip and play with"song.mid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't appear to be checking if the resource you're trying to get is returning something non-null.  Specifically:

```
song = MidiSystem.getSequence(
    getClass().getResource(filename));
```

is causing this particular problem.  There might be a deeper issue, which is that unless the resource represented by `filename` is actually in the jar, on the Class-Path or in the same directory as the jar file `getResource()` is not going to find it. If you're trying to access a file anywhere in the general filesystem (not in the jar file) then you should be using `File`:

```
song = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File(filename));
```

Comment: That really solve. Thank you! Now can I develop a midi software.